# Using geometrical objects independent from package

Tags: c++, cgal

I have a 3D mesh including points, cells, and faces. Instead of extending the capability of my code I would like to use a well established library, CGAL. I will still have my own code and CGAL will manage only geometrical portion.

The closest package to my case seems like to be Linear Cell Complex. In the following code (full example is [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Linear_cell_complex/Linear_cell_complex_2linear_cell_complex_3_8cpp-example.html)), what I don't like is the necessity to define `LCC_3` in order to create two tetrahedra. In my case, I would like to associate a tetrahedron to each of my mesh cells. So each time I do not want to create a `LCC_3`. Is there a simpler package than LCC to handle this situation? Can I make tetrahedron independent from package?

```
LCC_3 lcc;
// Create two tetrahedra.
Dart_handle d1 = lcc.make_tetrahedron(Point(-1, 0, 0), Point(0, 2, 0), 
                                      Point(1, 0, 0), Point(1, 1, 2));
Dart_handle d2 = lcc.make_tetrahedron(Point(0, 2, -1), Point(-1, 0, 1),
                                      Point(1, 0, -1), Point(1, 1, -3));
```

Comment: Creating a LCC_3 is required because this is the object that manage all the creations and operations. Anyway I don't think this is really painfull since it is created only once. There are other packages in CGAL that allow to deal with surfacic mesh only; but each of them need to create first an object, like for linear cell complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I fully understand your question. If you only need a geometric object (without connectivity), you can simply use CGAL::Tetrahedron_3, see http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Tetrahedron__3.html